# how to fix a broken symbolic link

Tags: linux, command

I am playing around Linux command within MobaXterm on Windows 10.  The Desktop/ shows after the ls command, however when I try to cd to the Desktop/, it shows "No such file or directory".  After check Desktop/ with the file command, it tells me "broken symbolic link to Desktop/".  How could I fix the broken symbolic link?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You figure out where it should point to, remove it, and create the correct link.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  Now realize I asked this question in the wrong place.